# What does it mean when emacs tells me "File mode specification error"?

Tags: emacs

This is the most useless error message I have ever seen.

I think it translates to .. "error".

The full error message from the ******Messages****** buffer is:

```
File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument characterp "string value here")
```

I think the latter part of that message means that emacs was expecting a character and got a string.

But how do I go about diagnosing just what it means when emacs tells me "File mode specification error" ?    and how do I narrow down where this error is originating?

How are these two errors (file mode error, expecting character and got string) related?

Comment: A little more context about the conditions under which the error is triggered would help

Comment: So, are you opening a file through find-file and at the end of opening the file Emacs reports this error?  Or are you calling normal-mode yourself?  What is the type of the file you are trying to open?

Comment: @vpit3833, I'm not trying to open a file.  not explicitly anyway.  I'm running some elisp code, but ... even that doesn't open a file, not even implicitly.  @Richard, I understand what you're asking, but I'm not seeking help in diagnosing *this particular error*.  I'm seeking an explanation for this ver common emacs error message.  It seems to pop up in many circumstances, often not (apparently) linked to opening a file at all.  I'm asking, *Why is that so?*

Comment: I saw your other questions. Are you getting this error after the upgrade to Emacs 23? The upgrade could have changed some function/variable behaviour that your elisp is expecting. May be there is an upgrade for that elisp if it is a package you downloaded from the net. Or, show the offending lines or the stacktrace you would get upon adding `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the beginning of your .emacs.  `normal-mode` is causing the error when attempting to load a major-mode.  This happens when opening a file.  See for yourself `\Ch-f normal-mode`.

Comment: yes, I get the error after upgrading to emacs23 .  Will post the update when I have a chance to dive in. Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error` <kbd>RET</kbd> to drop into the debugger when this (or any) error occurs -- assuming that this is a proper error, and not just a message. That gives you the stack trace, so you can figure out what caused it, and proceed from there (possibly with edebug, once you've determined which function(s) to instrument, but you can do plenty with the regular debugger).

Standard debugger commands:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Debugger Commands")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Main manual entry for debugging lisp (including edebug):
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Debugging")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

FYI, rgrep tells me that the only instance of the string "File mode specification error" in the *.el files for NTEmacs 23.2.1 appears in the `normal-mode` function definition:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `normal-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and thanks for doing the grep.  I'll look into `normal-mode` and see if I can make any sense of it.

Comment: Doesn't help me. Even if I have `toggle-debug-on-error` I still get the error without debugger ever starting up (this happens sometimes when I try to open file with `ido-find-file`, and it creates the buffer, but doesn't switch into it, if I switch then manually everything works fine). Any ideas?

Comment: dolzenko: In Emacs 24 at least, that message is *only* generated if `debug-on-error` is `nil`, so assuming that you are definitely toggling the variable ON and not OFF, then something else must be disabling `debug-on-error` before the error occurs.

Comment: For me, it happened because I use `(foo-mode +1)` instead of `(foo-mode 1)` . Thanks for `toggle-debug-on-error`.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to say what version of Emacs you are using.

If it's GNU Emacs 23, then the relevant code is in the function `normal-mode` in `files.el` and looks like this:

```
(report-errors "File mode specification error: %s"
  (set-auto-mode))
```

So the function `set-auto-mode` (or some function called from there) is signalling the `wrong-type-argument` error and `normal-mode` is adding the text `File mode specification error` in an attempt to help you track it down, but sadly it's not helping here, because the function of `set-auto-mode` is to determine which major mode a buffer should have, and then turn on that mode. I expect it's the mode itself that's signalling the error.

So phils' advice to turn on `debug-on-error` and look at the backtrace is a good one: that should give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened because I had an extra pair of `()` parenthesis around a function body I wrote. I guess that makes lisp attempt to execute the return value of the function body. So pay attention to your parenthesis count!