# Emacs lua-mode issue: (void-function interactively-called-p)

Tags: emacs, lua, lua-mode

I'm trying to install lua-mode (version 20110428) for emacs 21.4.1 and am having problems.  In my .emacs file I've got:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lua-mode/")
...
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.lua$" . lua-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(autoload 'lua-mode "lua-mode" "Lua editing mode." t)
```

I used the installation instructions from here: http://lua-mode.luaforge.net/  Also, in my .emacs.d/ dir I have lua-mode/ which contains lua-mode.el.  All of those files have the correct permissions.

Except now when I use emacs to open the new file "test.lua" I get the following message in the scratch buffer:

"File mode specification error: (void-function called-interactively-p)"

I'm running RHEL5.  I've looked online but haven't found much help.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I don't know any LISP (so it's hard to debug lua-mode.el) and apart from a handful of shortcuts, I don't know that much about emacs.

Thanks.

Comment: You've got a typo, for a start: `'("\\.lua$ . lua-mode)` should read `'("\\.lua$" . lua-mode)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a version of Emacs that doesn't have the version of the "called-interactively-p" function that takes 1 argument (earlier versions of the function didn't take an argument). You can get around this by putting this workaround (posted here: http://paste.lisp.org/display/115598/raw) in your Emacs init file:

```
(condition-case nil (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
  (error
   ; Save reference to called-interactively-p in
   ; inglorion-system-called-interactively-p
   (fset 'inglorion-system-called-interactively-p
         (symbol-function 'called-interactively-p))
   ; Define called-interactively-p so that it discards
   ; its arguments and calls inglorion-system-called-interactively-p
   (fset 'called-interactively-p
         (lambda (&rest args)
           (inglorion-system-called-interactively-p)))))
```

However, when I did this and attempted to test with Emacs 22, I encountered other errors as well due to certain functions not being present so you may have to upgrade your version of Emacs if you want to use lua-mode.

With Emacs 23 & 24, "lua-mode.el" seems to work (I'm not a lua programmer so I couldn't test it properly) with existing lua files but breaks when you attempt to create a new lua file. It's actually a bug in the "lua-mode.el" code that occurs when you try to open a new lua file (it doesn't occur if you attempt to open an existing lua file). The problem is that the "remove-text-properties" call at line# 1218 (in the "lua-unmark-multiline-literals" function) is calling the "remove-text-properties" function with a begin value of "1" and an end value of "0" (it's "0" because the buffer-size is "0" for a new file. You can fix this by changing line# 1218 from:

```
    (remove-text-properties (or begin 1) (or end (buffer-size)) '(syntax-table ()))
```

to:

```
    (remove-text-properties (or begin 1)
                            (or end
                                (if (> (buffer-size) 0)
                                    (buffer-size)
                                  (or begin 1)))
                            '(syntax-table ()))
```

You should let the developer of "lua-mode.el" know about the bug and possibly also request support for earlier Emacs versions.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to be the maintainer of lua-mode. I was lucky to stumble upon your problem when surfing on the internet and I the problem was solved after someone generously provided a backup implementation of `called-interactively-p` function.

Meanwhile, I must admit I was well aware that `called-interactively` logics were changed somewhere before emacs23, but I didn't bother changing it until someone would have filed it as a bug. This is merely an effort optimization since there've been numerous internal API changes in Emacs recently and fixing them preemptively simply doesn't fit into my timetable.

The bottomline is that:

1. I'll provide the backup implementation of called-interactively-p within lua-mode in nearest future which will get to next release.
2. And I'd like to encourage you to file such malfunctions as bugreports [here](https://github.com/immerrr/lua-mode/issues). I'm reading them regularly and your reports as well as your own hacks are welcome upstream.

Cheers,
immerrr.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function `called-interactively-p' just did not exist in Emacs 21.4.

But actually, I think you are talking about XEmacs, not GNU Emacs. Note that these are 2 different projects.

You should upgrade your XEmacs to 21.5 beta, or better (YMMV), use GNU Emacs 23 probably.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I was able to fix it by changing it to say:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.lua\\'" . lua-mode))
```

I can't claim to know why this makes a difference: I extrapolated from some other logic to load javascript mode which used a similar syntax to describe the file extension.

Comment: OK. I just checked, and I still do get an error when starting, which says `File mode specification error: (args-out-of-range 0 1)`. However, this https://github.com/immerrr/lua-mode/issues/4 commit suggests that this particular error I'm seeing is harmless. I do remember having your error though, I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question might provide a way to at least get a stack trace for your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180111/what-does-it-mean-when-emacs-tells-me-file-mode-specification-error