# Emacs lua-mode (File mode specification error)

Tags: emacs, lua, elisp

I get the following error

> File mode specification error: (error "Unknown rx form `group-n'")

when I try to edit a .lua file in emacs. I use GNU Emacs 23.3.1, and I have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(autoload 'lua-mode "lua-mode" "Lua editing mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.lua$" . lua-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("lua" . lua-mode))
```

I installed `lua-mode` from http://immerrr.github.com/lua-mode/.
I have tried to run emacs with the `--debug-init` option, but it did not enter the debugger, instead the .lua file opens in `text-mode` and not `lua-mode`..

(See also [Emacs lua-mode issue: (void-function interactively-called-p)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845464/emacs-lua-mode-issue-void-function-interactively-called-p))

Comment: *You need to make sure that `lua-mode.el` is on your load-path*.

Comment: I have the following in my `.emacs` file: `(add-to-list 'load-path   "~/.emacs.d/el-get/lua-mode/")`. In that directory I have `lua-mode.el` installed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Emacs is complaining because it knows nothing about `group-n` symbol used in `rx` macro in one of the recent commits, and that is probably because that symbol was only introduced in [Emacs 24.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.24.2) and your one is a bit older.

I must admit, when coding that I thought that `rx` package was much more mature and didn't even bother looking up its changes in Emacs news. So, there are two options here:

- either you update your Emacs to 24.2
- or you could downgrade to [older revision](https://github.com/immerrr/lua-mode/commit/7605d2c3d9cd6df4c89870a54c14c2c119102a2e)  and wait while I have the chance to rewrite that piece of code.

*UPD: the issue is fixed in upstream, the code is compatible with Emacs23 again.*

Comment: Should be fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/immerrr/lua-mode/commit/97ce427065ea630f171e8d0488ab016ad1c337ea). Please, try.

Comment: Thanks! I tried: `el-get-update "lua-mode"` from emacs.. Now the file opens in lua-mode, however there is now a new error `File mode specification error: (void-variable --elt-expected-re--)
Error during redisplay: (void-variable --elt-expected-re--)`

Comment: Apparently I've screwed up with compile-time-evaluated code. Please, try new commit in master.

Comment: I still get the same error.. I used `el-get-update "lua-mode"` from within Emacs..

Comment: You might need to recompile it, I'm not sure how el-get handles recompilation. Let me check for myself.

Comment: @HåkonHægland , works for me, sorry, what about `el-get-reinstall "lua-mode"`?