# spacemacs "file mode specification error"

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm running an up-to-date version of spacemacs, on the master branch. In my init file, I've got a number of cc-mode settings, including (as part of c-offsets-alist) "(innamespace . 0)". I'm finding that when I open a C++ file, I get the error "File mode specification error: (void-function innamespace)".

Here's the full set of c-offsets-alist modifications:

```
(c-offsets-alist            . ((access-label . -3)
                                 (brace-list-close . 0)
                                 (brace-list-entry . 0)
                                 (brace-list-intro . +)
                                 (class-close . 0)
                                 (class-open . 0)
                                 (defun-block-intro . +)
                                 (defun-close . 0)
                                 (defun-open . 0)
                                 (inclass . +)
                                 (label . 0)
                                 (statement . 0)
                                 (statement-cont . *)
                                 (topmost-intro-cont . 0)
                                 (arglist-close . c-lineup-arglist)
                                 (block-open . 0)
                                 (case-label . +)
                                 (func-decl-cont . c-lineup-java-throws)
                                 (inexpr-class . 0)
                                 (inher-cont . c-lineup-java-inher)
                                 (inline-open . 0)
                                 (substatement-open . 0)
                                 (innamespace . 0)
                                 ))
```

Here's the backtrace from the debugger:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function innamespace)
  (innamespace 0)
  (lambda nil (innamespace 0))()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook c-mode-common-hook c++-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook c-mode-common-hook c++-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(c++-mode-hook)
  c++-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(c++-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer geometry.cpp> "~/sandbox/cpp/geometry.cpp" nil nil "~/sandbox/cpp/geometry.cpp" (85065815 2049))
.
.
.
```

Interestingly, if I'm actually within a namespace, cc-mode honors my innamespace setting.  I've even commented out the setting in my init file, and still get the error.  Any ideas about how to deal with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181236

Comment: I recommend that you edit/paste your complete `c-offsets-alist` code into your question.  It sounds like Emacs is trying to *evaluate* `(innamespace . 0)`, but it will be easier to see where you've gone wrong if we can see the entire form.

Comment: `run-hooks` hands off to C code, so we lose some detail in the stack trace on that account.  I would start looking at the values (for the buffer in question) of the hook variables being processed there (starting with `c++-mode-hook`).

Comment: @phils Thanks for the suggestions. I'll do some digging tomorrow. It's funny - I use stow to maintain a couple of .emacs.d setups, but this 'innamespace' issue is limited to spacemacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, not surprisingly, the problem wasn't where I was looking. In addition to the bundle of settings that included the c-offsets-alist values that I showed in my original question, there was a form that I don't remember adding:

```
  (setq c++-mode-hook
        '(lambda ()
           (innamespace 0)))
```

I expect that I put it in carelessly - a copy and paste mishap, most likely. Let this be a cautionary tale - I should have caught this way before posting my question.